# how to find all possible flows in java code

Tags: java, analytics, analysis

(Java)

I would like to find all possible flows in my code and I am wondering if there is a tool that doing that or how I can do it myself.

For Instance, for the following naive piece of code:

```
public class InspectAllFlowsExample
{
    public void process(String name)
    {
        if(name == null)
            name = findName();
        else
        {
            verifyName(name);
        }
        processInternal(name);
    }

    private void processInternal(String name)
    {
        // Logic here
    }

    private boolean verifyName(String name)
    {
        return new Verifier().verify(name);     
    }

    private String findName()
    {       
        return "John";
    }
}

class Verifier
{
    public Verifier()
    {
    }

    boolean verify(String name)
    {
        return name.startsWith("B") ;
    }
}
```

possible flows are:

1. InspectAllFlowsExample#process --> InspectAllFlowsExample#findName --> InspectAllFlowsExample#processInternal
2. InspectAllFlowsExample#process --> InspectAllFlowsExample#verifyName -->  Verifier#new() --> Verifier#verify --> InspectAllFlowsExample#processInternal

Comment: Learn about [Unit Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)

Comment: @ZaidMalhis thanks for the comment but I'm afraid this is not what I'm looking for. Unless I'm mistaken, Unit Test does not inspect my code and provide me with all possible code flows...